# Retrive data based on pivot table in laravel

Tags: database, laravel-4, pivot, eloquent

I have those tables in my database

### Translation

1. id
2. translation_key_id
3. content

### Language

1. id
2. code (it would be "eng" or "ger" or "fre")

### translation_language

1. id
2. translation_id
3. language_id

Now the models are

```
class Language extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('id','code');
    protected $table = 'language';

    private $rules = array();

    public function translation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('translation','language_translation');
    }
}


class Translation extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array();
    protected $table = 'translation';

    private $rules = array();

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('language','language_translation');
    }
}
```

Now i want to retrieve those data which have `transkation_key_id = abc` (as for example ) and also with `code = "eng"`

How can i do that?

Comment: Which model do you want to retrieve?

Comment: i need the content which is write in english by the translation_key_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't see the need for pivot table here.

Show me why you need that, or change your relation to `belongsTo`. You can link translation with language using `id` (1) or `code` (2), which is unique obviously, right? So here it goes:

```
table translations: id, key, content, language_id (or language_code)

// Translation
public function language()
{
  // option 1
  return $this->belongsTo('Lanugage');
  // or 2:
  // return $this->belongsTo('Lanugage', 'language_code', 'code');
}t
```

then

```
// option 1
Translation::where('key', 'whatever')->whereHas('language', function ($q) {
   $q->where('code', 'eng');
})->first();

// option 2, even easier w/o any join needed
Translation::where('key', 'whatever')->where('language_code', 'eng')->first();
```

Comment: Here pivot table is only for creating many to many relationship between translation & language

Comment: I don't get it at all. Why do you need m-m, while it is 1-m?

Comment: Actually here many content is translated into many languages.So 1 content is being translated into many language and many translation could have same language translation.That's the logic behind that.Isn't it correct ???

Comment: would you explain the query you wrote so that i can use that for my other purposes ??

Comment: Check the docs. `whereHas` add join and constraint to the query, so it returns only those `parent` models, that have related rows matching given criteria. Now, about the design - is the content really linked with many languages? How? I would guess that `keyx -> 'some translated text'` will be right only for one language.

Comment: When i use Translation::where('key','whatever')->where('language_code','eng')->first()->content;

it show this error Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That means `first` returned `null`, ie. no row was found.

Comment: it's returns some value like this
{"id":20,"translation_key_id":25970,"content":"Born on the 29th of September 1982 in Colombo, Sri Lanka, Nuwan is the creative mind behind \"3Spire\u201d. Interested in art, design and technical development, he completed his master\u2019s degree in Information\u2019s Management and is working as a project manager in ","language_id":55,"created_at":"2014-11-26 09:57:03","updated_at":"2014-11-26 09:57:03"}

Comment: So it's ok, it returned `Translation` object, thus `->content` doesn't trigger that error you pasted. Look somewhere else for the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You've built relationships incorrect

try this

```
    class Language extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('id','code');
    protected $table = 'language';

    private $rules = array();

    public function translation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Translation','translation_language');
    }
}

class Translation extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array();
    protected $table = 'translation';

    private $rules = array();

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Language','translation_language');
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i need the what is the query i should write on this purpose